# Как читать логи apache2?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2, консоль, lamp

пытаюсь настроить 2 сайта на одном ip ( Ubuntu 16.04 +LAMP)

в etc/apache2/sites-available/magnitogorsk.party.conf

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAlias www.magnitogorsk.party
    ServerName magnitogorsk.party

    ServerAdmin sinecura92@mail.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magnitogorsk.party/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

в etc/apache2/sites-available/partyrobot.ru.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.

    ServerAlias www.partyrobot.ru
    ServerName partyrobot.ru

    ServerAdmin sinecura92@mail.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/partyrobot.ru/public_html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Оба сайта я активировал, стандартный .conf я отключил ( все действия делал под обычным пользователем с правами, а файлы правил через sftp под root

Но сайты не работают, не могу понять в чем проблема. в логах апача есть такие ошибки:

```
[Wed Nov 30 06:25:01.578085 2016] 
[mpm_event:notice] [pid 10791:tid 140448498636672] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 06:25:01.578119 2016] [core:notice] [pid 10791:tid 140448498636672] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 30 08:15:59.552220 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 10791:tid 140448498636672] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 30 08:39:02.114980 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 901:tid 140656255244160] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 08:39:02.116204 2016] [core:notice] [pid 901:tid 140656255244160] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 30 08:47:35.552144 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 901:tid 140656255244160] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 30 09:22:18.444210 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 890:tid 140665155405696] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 09:22:18.445675 2016] [core:notice] [pid 890:tid 140665155405696] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 30 10:52:20.192876 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 890:tid 140665155405696] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 30 10:52:21.339304 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6532:tid 140036243150720] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 10:52:21.339474 2016] [core:notice] [pid 6532:tid 140036243150720] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 30 11:00:11.747695 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6532:tid 140036243150720] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 30 11:12:40.029712 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 892:tid 140617992701824] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 11:12:40.030187 2016] [core:notice] [pid 892:tid 140617992701824] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 30 11:45:31.282484 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 892:tid 140617992701824] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 30 11:45:32.432622 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2698:tid 140241427892096] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 30 11:45:32.432846 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2698:tid 140241427892096] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Ребутал, апач, серв. Где то накосячил, помогите разобраться

Comment: содержимое внутри файлов в `/etc/apache2/sites-available` должно быть «завёрнуто» в тег *virtualhost*. [см. пример](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-ubuntu-14-04-lts-ru#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: Добавил полные файлы апач (обновил описание)